# Haskell - create artihmetic tree from prefix expression

Tags: haskell, recursion, tree, fold, postfix-notation

I want to create arithmetic binary tree from **prefix notation**.

My tree is defined as:

```
data Tree a = Leaf Int | Node Tree String Tree deriving (Show)
```

I want to convert it to arithmetic binary tree, like this:
[arithmetic tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJmPm.gif)

To evaluate prefix expression from string, I wrote this function:

```
evaluatePrefix:: String -> Int
evaluatePrefix expression = head (foldl foldingFunction [] (reverse (words  ( expression))) )
where   foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "*" = (x * y):ys  
        foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "+" = (x + y):ys  
        foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "-" = (x - y):ys  
        foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "/" = ( x `div` y):ys  
        foldingFunction xs numberString = read numberString:xs
```

Which is basically an algorithm from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation)

```
Scan the given prefix expression from right to left
for each symbol
 {
  if operand then
    push onto stack
  if operator then
   {
    operand1=pop stack
    operand2=pop stack
    compute operand1 operator operand2
    push result onto stack
   }
 }
return top of stack as result
```

Now I want to convert prefix expression **into the arithmetic tree**, so I can walk the tree and evaluate it that way, or convert it to postfix or infix.

**How could I do that?**

I thought of not evaluatig stack when folding, but instead creating nodes, but I don't know how to express it in Haskell.

**Can anybody give me a hint?**

Comment: Replace `x * y` with `Node x "*" y`, etc. Simpler yet, write `foldingFunction (x:y:ys) o | isOp o = Node x o y:ys` where `isOp` determines if the string is one of your operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a hint -- in your `foldingFunction` approach, the first argument is a list of numbers. Use the same approach, but this time the first argument will be a list of `Tree` values.

When the folding function comes across a number, e.g. "3", you'll want to push `Leaf 3` onto the stack.

When it comes across an operator like `*`, you'll want to push `Node x "*" y` where `x` and `y` are the `Tree` values of the top two values on the stack.